# Office conditional formatting broken by commas

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010

In my company, emails are displayed under the form ,  [].
For example, `Doe, John [Marketing]`.

Unfortunately I think the comma confuses the conditional formatting, if I choose to go in:

- View -> View Settings
- Conditional Formatting
- Add
- Condition
- tick Where I am 'the only person on the To line'

then all emails sent to John or Doe will be coloured, i.e. if an email is sent to `Smith, John`, then the email will be coloured as well, the comma seems to be interpreted as either of the words should match.

How can I get around this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your conditional formatting filters and put the filtering expression into double quotes, like

`"Doe, John [Marketing]"`

or just

`"Doe, John"`

When using double quotes, any potential special characters inside are treated as standard ones.

Comment: @BlueTrin – double quotes are common for the entire search engine, so you can also use them in message filtering box, which would otherwise have the same behaviour as you described.